# Multiple progress bars for multiple files upload firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I am working with Firebase Storage and trying to upload multiple files at a time. What I have done so far is, i get the files, and upload one by one to firebase and only one progress bar is there which shows the progress for each uploading file. What I need is, when i select the files, i want to create the progress bars equal to the number of files and they will start uploading and each progress bar will be shown its own progress.

**What I have done so far is :**

```js
var up = document.getElementById("fileUpload"),
    pr = document.getElementsByClassName("progress")[0];
    list = document.getElementsByClassName("list")[0];


//Listen for file selection
up.addEventListener('change', function(e){ 
    //Get files
    for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
        var imageFile = e.target.files[i];

        uploadImageAsPromise(imageFile,i);
    }
});

//Handle waiting to upload each file using promise
function uploadImageAsPromise (imageFile,i) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref($.cookie("_lo")+"/"+imageFile.name);

        //Upload file
        var task = storageRef.put(imageFile);

        //Update progress bar
        task.on('state_changed',
            function progress(snapshot){
                var percentage = snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes * 100;
                pr.value = percentage;
            },
            function error(err){

            },
            function complete(){
                var downloadURL = task.snapshot.downloadURL;
                console.log("file " + (i+1) + " Uplaoded");
                console.log(downloadURL);
            }
        );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the quickest Solution I came with :

```js
var up = document.getElementById("fileUpload"),
    pr = document.getElementsByClassName("progress");
    list = document.getElementsByClassName("list")[0];


//Listen for file selection
up.addEventListener('change', function(e){ 
    //Get files
    for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
        var imageFile = e.target.files[i];
        list.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin','<li class="row">'+
                    '<div class="col-4">'+imageFile.name+'</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-4">'+imageFile.size+'</div>'+
                    '<progress value="0" max="100" class="progress"></progress>'+
                   '</li>');
        uploadImageAsPromise(imageFile,i);
    }
});

//Handle waiting to upload each file using promise
function uploadImageAsPromise (imageFile,i) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref($.cookie("_lo")+"/"+imageFile.name);

        //Upload file
        var task = storageRef.put(imageFile);

        //Update progress bar
        task.on('state_changed',
            function progress(snapshot){
                var percentage = snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes * 100;
                pr[i].value = percentage;
            },
            function error(err){

            },
            function complete(){
                var downloadURL = task.snapshot.downloadURL;
                console.log("file " + (i+1) + " Uplaoded");
                console.log(downloadURL);
            }
        );
    });
}
```