# how to get progress value while uploading multiple files to Firebase Storage?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

When uploading a file to Firebase Storage we get the progress value by listening to the task snapshot event.

```
 uploadTask.snapshotEvents.listen((event) {
        setState(() {
          _progress =
              event.bytesTransferred.toDouble() / event.totalBytes.toDouble();
          print(_progress.toString());
        });
        if (event.state == TaskState.success) {
          _progress = null;
          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'File added to the library');
        }
      }).onError((error) {
        // do something to handle error
  });
```

this will help to improve ui while uploading and let the user know that something is happening. but when it comes to uploading multiple files we use different method.

```
Future<String> uploadFile(File file) async {
    setState(() {
      uploading = true;
      isError = false;
    });
    final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
    final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final uuid = Uuid();

    Reference ref =
        storageRef.child('posts/${auth.currentUser!.email!}/${uuid.v1()}');

    final uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);

    final taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() => null);
    String url = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return url;
  }
```

so using this method can i get the progress value?

Comment: Since you still have an upload task in that second snippet, you can still call `listen` on it to monitor its progress. Did you try that? What happened? Any error message?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen actually i've tried the `listen` method, and it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you tried. Note that "doesn't return anything" is typically hard to help with, so I recommend printing values and showing what logging output you get from that and what you expected instead.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen when i upload it works for the first time on first run. but on the second it doesn't actually do anything. it just loads. but if i re run the app again it sends data

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen when i test it now without the listener, it doesn't upload second time. but if i stop running the app and re run it it upload fine. but again it doesn't upload for the second time until i rerun it. why is that?

Comment: can you have a look at this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74170565/how-to-show-progress-bar-while-uploading-multiple-images-to-firebase-storage) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48371457/multiple-progress-bars-for-multiple-files-upload-firebase)